# Creating thematic map where individual values are displayed as colors and range values are displayed as shades of those colors?

Tags: mapinfo, thematic-map

I am trying to create the following thematic map using Mapinfo professional:

I have point data that is displayed as a grid. I need to create a thematic map where I show two fields - one representing the land use type (individual values) and one representing  emissions (ranges). I need to show each of the four land use types with different colors. The shade i.e. darkness of each color represent the emissions produced by that land use type. I want to make two legends, one displaying the land uses (colors), one showing the ranges for emission data.

Below is an example of what I am trying to create.

[image: Example of the thematic map I want to create]

Answer (score 2):

I think you're effectively trying to create a bivariate thematic.

To do this most easily in Mapinfo, as referenced in the MI Pro help under **Bivariate Thematic Mapping**:

**1.    Do one of the following:**

Create a thematic map. Choose Map > Create Thematic Map and select the Ranges type with a transparent style. Continue setting the options until you get to Create Thematic Map - Step 3 of 3 wizard panel.

Open and modify an existing map. Choose Map > Modify Thematic Map to open the Modify Thematic Map dialog box.

**2.    Click Styles:**

The Customize Range Styles dialog box opens.

**3.    Select the Replace Layer Style check box to enable bi-variant layer support:**

The Replace Layer Style check box controls whether the layers under the Range theme should be drawn. When this check box is selected, the layer(s) under the theme are not drawn. When this check box is cleared, the layer(s) under the theme are drawn.

The default behavior of the Replace Layer Style check box is set in the Map Window Preferences dialog box. See Setting the Default Behavior of the Replace Layer Style Check Box.

**4.    Click OK:**

Your theme displays. When there are other thematic layers beneath this one, you can see the bi-variant effect.